# Use decorators to wrap all functions with "if func returned false, return false"

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm writing a very basic Python script based on a `main` function that sequentially calls other functions.

What I would like to do is to wrap all of the functions that are called from `main` with something like:

```
result = func(*some_args):
   if (result != True):
       return result
```

For example, for this code:

```
def func1(arg1 , arg2):
     if (some_cond):
        return False #Or some err_val
     return True

def func2(arg1):
     if (some_cond):
        return False
     return True

def main():
    func1(val1 , val2)
    func2(val3)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     result = main()
     if (result == err_val1):
          # Do something. Maybe print. Maybe call some function.
          sys.exit(1)
```

I want that if one of the functions fails `main` would break and return its error. Can I do this using decorators?

Comment: Why not just use exceptions ?

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: *"I want that if one of the functions fails - main() would break and return its error"* – Yup, that's *exceptions* you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want to throw exceptions around for any reason that any of the funcs may fail. It's a normal behavior - I just want the main() to break if it happens.

Comment: Then you're looking to logically concatenate your functions...? `func1() and func2()`...?

Comment: How are you capturing the return value of `main`, exactly? Python isn't like C. The `main` function isn't special, and its return value isn't automatically returned to the calling environment. If you want that behaviour you have to do it explicitly, by raising the SystemExit exception, or by calling the `sys.exit` function which raises SystemExit for you.

Comment: @Hodor in Python, throwing an exception **is** the normal behaviour.

Comment: Even a simple `for` loop is terminated via the StopIteration exception.

Comment: @deceze - You're absolutely right. There's a whole "if __name__ == "main"" part as well. This is the part the checks what main returns and exits (or not etc.). I'll edit the code to make it more clear.

Comment: Use backticks `` to signify code in comments, rather than wrapping in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what exceptions are built for in Python.

```
# imports belong at the *top* of the file
import sys


class SomeDescriptiveError(Exception): pass
class SomeOtherSpecialError(Exception): pass


def func1(arg1 , arg2):
     if (some_cond):
        raise SomeDescriptiveError('Cannot frobnosticate the fizzbuzz')
     return arg1 + arg2
     # or skip the return statement altogether

def func2(arg1):
     if (some_cond):
        raise SomeOtherSpecialError('The frontobulator is no longer cromulent')
     return ''.join(reversed(arg1))

def main():
    print(func1(val1 , val2))
    print(func2(val3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     try:
         result = main()
     except SomeDescriptiveError as e:
         print('Oh dear')
         sys.exit(e.args[0])
     except SomeOtherSpecialError as e:
         print('Oh no')
         sys.exit(e.args[0])
     else:
         print('All systems are fully operational')
     finally:
         print('I really should clean up all these bits.')
```

Comment: This code is more versatile than mine, and more efficient, since it doesn't incur the overhead of an extra function call for each function due to the use of decorators. But I guess mine _looks_ slightly cleaner, and requires less modification of existing code. :)

Answer (score 3):

I maintain that the best solution would be the use of exceptions. If that's absolutely not what you want, you can do some short-circuiting:

```
return func1() and func2()
```

To extend this to more functions without a ton of `and`s:

```
from functools import partial

def main():
    funcs = (partial(func1, arg1, arg2),
             partial(func2, arg1))

    if any(!f() for f in funcs):
        return False
```

Though this doesn't return "its error" (the failed function's error), it just returns `False`. If you want to differentiate more between different kinds of errors... well, you're back to exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, what you really want is a universal exception catcher, that would catch and return the exception of any wrapped function. You can easily do it this way.

```
def return_exception(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    return wrapper
```

Example

```
In [3]: @return_exception
   ...: def div(a, b):
   ...:     return a / b
   ...: 

In [4]: div(1, 0)
Out[4]: ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
```

So then you can process the return exception object the way you want, though it's pretty hard to say why you need that.

**Update** As others have noted it's generally good to only catch particular exceptions. You can modify the decorator slightly.

```
def return_exception(*exception_types):
    def build_wrapper(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exception_types as e:
                return e
        return wrapper
    return build_wrapper
```

Example:

```
In [6]: @return_exception(ZeroDivisionError)
   ...: def div(a, b):
   ...:     return a / b
   ...: 

In [7]: div(0, 1)
Out[7]: 0.0

In [8]: div(1, 0)
Out[8]: ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')

In [9]: div(1, "a")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

In [10]: @return_exception(ZeroDivisionError, TypeError)
   ....: def div(a, b):
   ....:     return a / b
   ....: 

In [11]: div(1, 0)
Out[11]: ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')

In [12]: div(1, "a")
Out[12]: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'")
```

As you see, you only catch the specified exceptions (you can still specify the universal `Exception` class, though).

Comment: I've actually using similar mechanism in some other part of this project.
I wanted to avoid exceptions in this case - but considering all the responses I got here it seems that I'm wrong.

Comment: @Hodor: FWIW, it's generally better to catch specific exceptions rather than the generic `Exception`, as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/4014959).

Comment: @PM2Ring although I wholeheartedly concur, the OP can check the class of the exception object once it's returned.

Comment: @Hodor exceptions aren't *great* as typical control flow (though sure, Python uses `StopIteration` for `for` loops), but there are *plenty* of reasons that you can have "exceptional" circumstances in your code that you should handle/deal with. There's nothing wrong with using exceptions in those cases.

Comment: @Eli Korvigo Thanks a lot! I agree it's better to catch specific exceptions only. Regardless, after reading all the comments here I've decided with Wayne Werner's solution - it seems more readable and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Since you *do* actually want the program to die when one of these errors occurs you might as well raise `SystemExit`. Here's a way to do it with a decorator.

```
flag = 2

def die_on_not_True(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        rc = func(*args)
        if rc is not True:
            fmt = 'Function {} failed with return value {!r}'
            print(fmt.format(func.__name__, rc))
            raise SystemExit(1)
        return True
    return wrapper

@die_on_not_True
def func1(arg1 , arg2):
     if arg1 == flag:
        return 'error 1' 
     return True

@die_on_not_True
def func2(arg1):
     if arg1 == flag:
        return 'error 2'
     return True

def main():
    val1, val2, val3 = 1, 2, 3
    print(func1(val1, val2))
    print('one')
    print(func2(val3))
    print('two')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
True
one
True
two
```

If we set `flag = 1`, the output becomes

```
Function func1 failed with return value 'error 1'
```

If we set `flag = 3`, the output becomes

```
True
one
Function func2 failed with return value 'error 2'
```

When `flag` equals 2, the exit status of 0 is returned to the shell, when `flag` equals 1 or 3, the exit status of 1 is returned.

---

If you want to do further processing after printing the error message, then raise a custom exception instead of `SystemExit` and catch it by wrapping your `main` call in a `try...except`.