# Handling Exceptions in Python 3.6

Tags: python, exception, python-3.6, try-except

I am trying to handle exceptions in Python 3.6. I want to handle every possible exception and print the exception. When i do

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError("Test")

except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

it just prints

> class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'

How do i get the message of the Exception? In this case i would like the output to be "Test".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: about catching ANY exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can catch and `print` the `Exception` as follows:

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError("Test")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Test
```

I'm not quite sure why you're trying to catch *every* `Exception` though, it would seem more prudent to let Python handle and `raise` these for you in general. Normally you would only catch *specific* `Exception`s.

This behavior is not specific to Python 3.6.

Comment: I am connecting to a database and there can be many different Exceptions, so i don't want to handle every of these. But it's working, thank you

Comment: @no0by5 You should catch only the `Exception`s you expect to see and want to handle, e.g. `except RuntimeError`