# Differentiate errors arising in python

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I am quite newby into dealing with exceptions in python.

Particularly I would like to create an exception when:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>`
```

and another one when:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

If i am right it shall be in both cases a  :

```
except IOError:
```

however I would like to carry out one code when one error arises and a different code when the other error arises,

How could I differentiate these 2 exceptions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set several exception handlers for each type of exception you want to handle, like this:

```
import urllib2

(...)

try:
    (... your code ...)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    (... handle HTTPError ...)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    (... handle URLError ...)
```

Note that this will handle ONLY `HTTPError` and `URLError`, any other kind of exception won't be handled. You can add a final `except Exception, e:` to handle anything else, although [this is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception) as correctly pointed out in the comments.

Obviously replace evrything that's in parenthesis () with your code.

Comment: Correct, but I suggest to mention that handling generic exception is not a good practice in Python. Cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception

Comment: Agreed, that's why I didn't put it in the main code example block. Will update the answer to note this, thank you.