# Win32Com Save As Variable Name in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I'm trying to loop through .xlsb file types in a folder and convert them to .csv in Python 3+ and Windows 10 and have pieced together the code below with help from SO. I want to save the new .csv as the original .xlsb name but am having issues - I have this so far:

```
import os
import glob
import win32com.client

path = r'C:\Users\folder\Desktop\Test Binary'
all_files_test = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsb"))
for file in all_files_test:
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False
    doc = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    doc.SaveAs(Filename="C:\\Users\\folder\\Desktop\\Test Binary\\file.csv",FileFormat = 6) #overwrites file each time, need to substitute 'file'
    doc.Close(True)
    excel.Quit()
excel.Quit()
```

Which of course just overwrites each new iteration each time as 'file.csv'. How can I substitute the .xlsb name for each .csv name to SaveAs separate files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parfait's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905298/5223757) is good, but has a few flaws. I have remedied those (that I have noticed) in this answer, and refactored out some context managers to make the logic easier to understand (and hence easier to modify).

It now prints failed files to `sys.stdout` (to let you recover, Unix-style, by replacing the `for` loop with repeated `input()` / `f.readline()[:-1]` calls), and only opens the Excel COM object once; this should be a lot faster.

I have also added support for recursively performing this match, but this feature requires Python 3.5 or above in order to work.

```
import os
import glob
import traceback
from contextlib import contextmanager
import win32com.client
from pythoncom import com_error

PATH = r'C:\Users\folder\Desktop\Test Binary'

@contextmanager
def open_excel():
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False
    try:
        yield excel
    finally:
        excel.Quit()

@contextmanager
def open_workbook(excel, filename):
    doc = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    try:
        yield doc
    finally:
        doc.Close(True)

all_files_test = glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH, "**.xlsb"), recursive=True)

with excel_cm() as excel:
    for file in all_files_test:    
        try: 
            with open_workbook(file) as doc:
                doc.SaveAs(Filename=file[:-4] + 'csv', FileFormat=6)
        except com_error as e:
            print(file)
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: This is practically my answer! And `Exception as e` [catches *any* raised error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/1422451).

Comment: @Parfait I know, which is why it's not the best plan to use `Exception`; it doesn't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` et al. as `BaseException` would have, but we don't want to catch an `IndexError`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `str.replace` on *file* variable to change extension. And consider wrapping in `try/except` to cleanly release COM objects regardless of error or not.

```
path = r'C:\Users\folder\Desktop\Test Binary'

all_files_test = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsb"))

for file in all_files_test:    
    try: 
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = False
        doc = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)

        csv_name = file.replace('.xlsb', '.csv')

        doc.SaveAs(Filename = csv_name, FileFormat = 6)
        doc.Close(True)
        excel.Quit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:    
        doc = None
        excel = None
```

And to go one level deeper use combination of `os.path.basename` and `os.path.join`:

```
path = r'C:\Users\folder\Desktop\Test Binary'

...
csv_name = os.path.basename(file).replace('.xlsb', '.csv')

doc.SaveAs(Filename = os.path.join(path, 'Conversion_Files', csv_name), FileFormat = 6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this does it perfectly.

Comment: That will fail in the case of `C:\My xlsb document.xlsb`; instead trim the string with slice syntax. Also, don't catch `Exception` if there's something more specific you can catch.

Comment: @Hatt It has two small errors that might cause problems later down the line, but they're easily remedied.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You mean the answer has two small errors? My entire process here is take a bunch of .xlsb files (still need to explicitly take the correct tab), convert to csv, concatenate csvs into one file with a new column containing original file name, and analyze. Will that cause any issues?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 In this specific instance it should only show up in the file extension - basically we have many locations that use a legacy .xlsb workbook as a form and save their data with the original file name and their location. I could rewrite the all_files_test variable - I just started the script off that way but sounds like there's a cleaner/safer way to do it.

Comment: Ah - gotcha - I'll go ahead and make the switch now, might as well keep as safe as possible.
@wizzwizz4 Sorry one other question - it sounds simple but I'm getting errors just now - if i wanted to change the out folder to one level deeper (Conversion_Files) how can I add that in? And thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: @Hatt There were too many changes for me to post in comments, so I've posted an answer.

Comment: @Hatt, you can also use period in the replace to match on extension. I doubt files will contain *xlsb* in the name. Also, to go one level deeper, use `os.path.join` on the *path* string. See edit.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for that edit - I tried that four different ways but should have gone back to os. Thank you for that update.