# Python decorator for backoff retries in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I have a class named Client which tries to connect to a server via Websockets. I tried to make a decorator to retry if it couldn't connect to the server but I get the error

```
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <__main__.Client object at 0x000001BE86D71930>
```

The code is this:

```
def retry(fnc):
    def f_retry(self):
        tries = 2
        delay = 2
        backoff = 2
        while tries > 1:
            try:
                return self.main()
            except Exception as e:
                msg = "%s, Retrying in %d seconds..." % (str(e), delay)
                print(msg)
                time.sleep(delay)
                tries -= 1
                delay *= backoff
        return self.main()

    return f_retry

class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name= None
        
    @retry
    async def main(self):
        try : 
            async with websockets.connect(
                'ws://localhost:8000',
            ) as ws:
                logging.info("Connected to the server")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    asyncio.run(client.main())
```

This algorithm is inspired from [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419395/implementing-a-retry-routine)

Comment: I suspect that `f_retry` should be `async`.

Comment: @quamrana I tried making it an `async` function but now I get maximum `recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are decorating an `async` function, you need to make your wrapper `async` and `await` the result of the function:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import wrap
def retry(fnc):
    @wraps(fnc)
    async def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
        tries = 2
        delay = 2
        backoff = 2
        while tries > 1:
            try:
                return await fnc(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                msg = "%s, Retrying in %d seconds..." % (str(e), delay)
                print(msg)
                await asyncio.sleep(delay)
                tries -= 1
                delay *= backoff
        return await fnc(*args, **kwargs)

    return f_retry
```

I've fixed a few more things:

1. Use `functools.wraps`
   `functools.wraps` helps decorators behave more like the functions they wrap.
2. Make it care about the argument
   Instead of just using `self.main`, this is now more versatile, can be used for methods and functions with any arguments, and any name.
3. Fix `RecursionError`
   Previously, it would call `self.main`, which was itself. Now it calls the passed function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I try using it I get this `maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`. Maybe because of the decorator, the function is called infinite times