# try except block not executing (but finally does)

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

My python script is (single threaded) running for many hours, however, after some time it suddenly stops. We used a `try-except` block to debug the error. However, this behaves very strange. We use:

```
try:
    while True:
        # do routine
        time.sleep(someSeconds)
except Exception as e:
    # exception!
finally:
    # finish
```

The while routine is executing normally, then the script (aka main thread) falls asleep, wakes up and executes the routine again. After hours the finally block gets executed, *without* the exception block being executed (first).

How can this be? [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/4673476), when the `while True` loop stops for *any* reason, the except block should be executed (before finally)? How can it be that the error is not caught?

Note: there is no return/ break in the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

- your “routine” exits the loop using `return` or `break`.
- An exception is raised which does not derive from `Exception` (add an `except: print(“other exception”)` to test this)

Comment: For the Sexton option: How do I get the name of this other exception? In the linked answer, the person says that ‘except Exception’ should catch every exception. And I thought any Exception inherits from *Exception*?

Comment: Not all exceptions derive from Exception. KeyboardInterrupt derives from BaseException for example. I found this example how to get the exception caught in the `except:` clause: `print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])`