# Raising Python exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I am aware of how to raise exceptions and how to catch them, but how do you know when to raise a certain common exception such as KeyError or ValueError? And why couldn't you just always raise the generic *Exception* if any exception handling behaviour treats all exceptions the same?

I am not sure if this comes down to personal stylistic preference or if there is a best practice for this. For context, this question was prompted by writing a kind of switch statement for file names that follows this kind of logic (this is not my actual code):

```
if a:
  return b
elif c:
  return d
else:
  raise Exception("letter not a or c")
```

I know switch cases came in Python 3.10, but this is a question about exceptions rather than any specific coding problem.

Comment: This particular example calls for using `dict` instead of complex if/elif/else and if the missing key should raise an exception it would/should be `KeyError`. For general discussion on when/should I use custom exception, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/57165380/4046632

Comment: "any exception handling behaviour treats all exceptions the same" That statement is false.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the exception handling you have written?

Comment: A search engine had this one in the top 3 for "site:stackoverflow.com Python raise exception"...