# How to handle time library exceptions?

Tags: python, time, shared-libraries

I'm currently working on a project where it is critical that i can demonstrate  how a program should behave in case an error occurs. In this instance, i want my program to except any errors that may be produced by a failed `time.localtime()` call.

I understand that an error like this is highly unlikely to occur. Regardless, I would like to cover all possibilities. Therefore, what type of error would occur if my program was unable to get a response from `time.time()` or `time.localtime()`?

```py
try:
   time = time.time()
except #nameoferror:
   print ("Unable to get current time")
```

What could i replace `"#nameoferror"` with in order to output the message if the time function failed?

Comment: Going by the documentation, it looks like time.time() does not throw any error as such.

Comment: If you don't know the exception type, use `except Exeception as exc:` to catch all built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions. You should generally `print` or otherwise log the problem in the handler so you can determine which one it was (if you care).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I recommend you check out [this post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception) as well.

This is an interesting question! Usually, when you're writing a try/except, you'd catch the exception type that would be thrown if the error that you're anticipating occurs (as I think you already know).

For example: let's say we have variable `var1`, and it happens to be equal to string value of `"hello"`. If you ran `var2 = int(var1))`, Python would throw a `ValueError` exception. Because you may expect that, you could write something like:

```
var1 = "hello"

try:
    int(var1)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid casting attempt on non-numeric value.")
```

In your case, you are dealing something that is very unlikely (if ever) to happen. To handle cases like this, you can write generic `except` handling. This way, you are not catching a particular type of exception. You are catching *any* exception that may be thrown as a result of the attempted logic.

Example:

```
var1 = "hello"

try:
    time = time.time()
except:
    print("Error occurred during try statement.")
    # return value if this is part of a function/handling of your choice
```

Perhaps others will have a better example, but this is how I would handle an exception if I am unsure of what particular type may be thrown.