# Extract data from sql in python (one time per second)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, plotly-dash

how do i extract data from sql in python?
I have this code but it is repeating all the values which is not what i want.
I wish to have new updated sql data to be in my python. I am almost struck for a few days..Any kind soul pls
I am using sqlserver2012, python

```
import time
sql_conn = connectSQLServer('ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP-K6A10IO\SQLEXPRESS', 'display')

mycursor = sql_conn.cursor()

a = 0
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        a=a+1
        print(a)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer"    
        mycursor.execute(sql)

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        for x in myresult:
            print(x)


    except Exception as error:
        print("Nothing in database\n")
        print(error)
sql_conn.commit()
```

```
The result shown is 
1
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
2
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
3
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
(1622, 20)
while i wish to have a constantly updating to the end of the list like:
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
after 1 second
(1622, 20)
after 1 second
(1612, 10)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? As an aside, using `except Exception as error:` like that is bad practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception

Comment: Ok, noted. I wish to have new data records(1 per s) coming from sql to my python, which i cant do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this right, you only want to see **new** records (those added since the previous query). You need to add some logic in your application.

Your table probably already has an auto-incremented ID (or a timestamp of some sort could do). After each query, you need to memorize the maximum value you got, and the subsequent query should include a `WHERE` clause (ie `WHERE ID > nnnnn`) so that you only get records having an ID **greater** than that maximum value from your previous query.

Alternatively you could use a datetime value but this could be less accurate (unless you don't mind some overlap).

This query simply returns everything.

PS: I don't know why you have a commit in your exception handling block. You are not doing any transaction here, you are not writing any data to the DB either. Variable `a` is not used.

Comment: Hi there, yes, i would only want to see new records. Yes, my table does have the auto-incremented id. Do you have a example of the subquery?

Comment: @uiu808 there are instructions here about how to pass parameters into SQL from python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score 1):

If editing the table schema is not an option it may be possible to get close to what you want with the following line...

```
  for row in cursor.execute("""SELECT num,id ,row_number() partition by (select 1) FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer"""):
```

*Edit*

Seeing you can change the schema, add a column for dating edited in the table you are querying.

```
 for row in cursor.execute("""SELECT num,id FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer where datetime> dateadd(s,-1,getdate())"""):
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply! Ok ill try! I have been struck for days omg

Comment: Do you have any record or when the table was edited in SQL? If the SQL table has a datetime edited column would make your task much easier

Comment: I have tried both functions by printing the rows but it seemed to be unable to retrieve the data

Comment: You will have to add a 'Datetime' column to make it work. The row_number may be incorrect syntax or not supported in mssql2012. I can't really test, all this is off my phone

Comment: Yeap, i did add the datetime column as datetime to test for the second code. Really appreciate your help here!