# Include stderr and stdout when logging in python

Tags: python, error-logging

Having the following logging:

```py
log_name = pd.datetime.now().date().strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d")+".log" #Current day
log_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))+"/logs/" #Path
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_path+log_name,filemode="a",level = logging.INFO)
```

is there a way to catch "Unknown" exceptions (such as `pd.to_sql` errors due to e.g typo in the column name) and write them to the same logger file specified in `logging.basicConfig`  without having try/catches all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times i use a combination of traceback library(standard) and a very big try-except clause under lets say main() function.So any uncaught error can be logged without special treatment.
I hope fits your needs.
Example:

```
import logging
import traceback

try:
    main()
except:
    logger.warning(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: That's exactly the point I referred to as "without having try/catches all over the place", since they are where you can expect an error, but if the error is unexpected it is not caught

Comment: Why not use `logger.exception`?

Comment: In a try/catch ? I want a way to catch un-wanted exceptions and log that. In a try/catch you expect an exception to be there. I could of course wrap the entire `main()` in a `try: main; except Exception as e: logging.except(e)` but I doubt that is the cleanest way to do so.

Comment: As @DanielWalker suggested logger.exception can be used,but traceback will log a whole lot of more info.As it seems there was already a popular question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception with no siginifcant other methodologies.The methodology i suggested works the way you expect.I dont think there is a real alternative other than try-except.