# Why am I unable stop this program using the VSCode terminal command: ctrl + c, or ctrl + z?

Tags: python

Background:

1. This was not an issue until I added the try/except. I added this because at times I feel there was a deeper issue, perhaps rooted in the function I call from kucoin.helpers. (I call a while loop, while inside of a while loop in my code.)
2. Specifically I would find myself unable to consistently finish the cycle of purchase and then sale of asset: This failure would stem from between a successful purchase of asset and the sale.
3. The try/except loop was the only way to "flawlessly execute my code".
4. I know the try/except loop was not utilized properly, I am inexperienced and will delve into it.

```
import kucoin_helpers
import time
import random
from twilio.rest import Client as TwilioClient 
import twiliodata

####Set API Credentials for Twilio
text_client = TwilioClient(twiliodata.account_sid, twiliodata.auth_token)
#This is going to be Lumiere himself. The man, the bot, the first iteration and legend.
########IMMEDIATELY BEGIN KEEPING rounds of data. 
                    #Leave room for INFO: in database to allow comment made to first and last entry in database for round
                        ##This will allow for easy diefin tin
                    #look forward to using minimax  
take_profit = 0
stop_loss = 0
keep_testing = True
while keep_testing:   
    try:            
    starting_account_balance = kucoin_helpers.doge_musk_check_balance()
    print(f"BEGINNING BALANCE: {starting_account_balance}")

    list_of_winLOSS = []
    ####Start keeping this data
    total_times_to_run = random.randrange(start=20, stop=50)
    total_times_to_run = int(total_times_to_run)

    #####We need to run this loop repetitively until we reach an output ratio where Success to Failure is near (0.7/0.3)==2.63
    #Add Each trials results (tp to sl limits/)
        ##Consider using limits that are proportionate to the "confidence" in current trend in timeframe

    for i in range(total_times_to_run):
        input_tp = random.uniform(1.001, 1.009)
        take_profit=input_tp
        print(input_tp)
        input_sl = random.uniform(0.991, 0.99989)
        take_profit=input_sl
        print(input_sl)
        answer = kucoin_helpers.execute_doge_musktrade(input_tp=input_tp, input_sl=input_sl)
        list_of_winLOSS.append(answer)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    failure = 0
    success = 0
    for outcome in list_of_winLOSS:
        if outcome == "Failure":
            failure += 1
        if outcome == "Success":
            success += 1


    ending_account_balance = kucoin_helpers.doge_musk_check_balance()


    total_PNL = ending_account_balance - starting_account_balance

    print(f"SUCCESS: {success}\nFailure: {failure}")
    print(f"BEGINNING BALANCE: {starting_account_balance}")
    print(f"ENDING BALANCE: {ending_account_balance}")
    print(f"PNL : {total_PNL}")
    body = f"SUCCESS: {success}\nFAILURE: {failure}\nBEGINNING BALANCE: {starting_account_balance}\nENDING BALANCE: {ending_account_balance}\nPNL: {total_PNL}"
    text_client.messages.create(to="7177295751", from_=twiliodata.phone_number, body=body)
    
except:
    print("Unable to perform Action")
```

Comment: Because you have a catch-all `except:` in your code which catches _all_ exceptions, including `KeyboardInterrupt` on some systems. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/843953

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)

Comment: Can you elaborate further on the is catch-all except? I am very very not adept in the try/except functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, a good use of try-except clauses would capture your specific exceptions and not all. What is happening right now is that you are throwing a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception by pressing Ctrl+c, which is caught by your except statement and results in printing `"Unable to perform Action"`.

You could add an exception handler for the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception with `exit()` to end the program, ones you hit Ctrl+c:

```
try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
except:
    print("Unable to perform Action")
```

Comment: MY Man. You both answered my question perfectly. Thank you very much and I will delve into better utilizing try/except functions than. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the code block exactly as it is being run? Because if not, you might have some indentation issues. From what I can tell, from `starting_account_balance = kucoin_helpers.doge_musk_check_balance()` to `except: print("Unable to perform Action")` should be one indent further in.

Comment: This is not exactly as it is. Here is a link to the github page where I have the data, this isnt updated with the branch I have created on my pc, but the concept is there, and the differences are not relevant to outcome, just minor differences like percentage changes and adding random() functions.

https://github.com/Gershwinfire/trading_algorithms

Comment: Ok, glad to help!