# How to catch Error in telegram_send when there is no connection to the internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I'm trying to add a try-catch to my script that is supposed to notify my when my script is done executing using `telegram_send()`. So I ran the script with the internet connection off to see what error is raised by the function so I could catch it and add a small `print()` message to inform the user that the internet was out. What I got, however is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 140, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 614, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 360, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 857, in _validate_conn
    super(HTTPSConnectionPool, self)._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 289, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 149, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014144AA8100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 259, in _request_wrapper
    resp = self._con_pool.request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\request.py", line 68, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(method, url, fields=fields,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\request.py", line 148, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 244, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 691, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(method, url, body, headers, retries,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 691, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(method, url, body, headers, retries,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 691, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(method, url, body, headers, retries,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /TOKEN/sendMessage (Caused by NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014144AA8100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Documents\GitHub\QSAR-Versuch\ROC.py", line 212, in <module>
    telegram_send.send(messages=['OI',time_string])
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram_send\telegram_send.py", line 246, in send
    message_ids += [send_message(m, parse_mode)["message_id"]]
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram_send\telegram_send.py", line 228, in send_message
    return bot.send_message(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 133, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 525, in send_message
    return self._message(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 339, in _message
    result = self._post(endpoint, data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 298, in _post
    return self.request.post(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 361, in post
    result = self._request_wrapper(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 265, in _request_wrapper
    raise NetworkError(f'urllib3 HTTPError {error}') from error
telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot5484246240:TOKEN/sendMessage (Caused by NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014144AA8100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Now call me crazy, but I find that traceback to be slightly confusing. I am used to having a simple builtin error raised by python so I'm at a loss what to do in this case, since it seems like there is a custom error type that I'd need to import from urlib or something and then make the try-catch with that. So, how do I fix this? Is there a hacky way to do it?

Not really useful, but here's a script example:

```py
import telegram_send

try:
    telegram_send.send(messages=['OI!'])
except SomeErrorIfInternetIsOut:
    print('There was no internet connection.')
```

EDIT: I tried to import socket.gaierror and checking for that, but no chage. The traceback stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to [catch the error without specifying the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/how-can-i-write-a-try-except-block-that-catches-all-exceptions), you can see the error type is `telegram.error.NetworkError` (which is the last one in your stack trace).

Then, if you want to write an except statement specific to this error, you can first `import telegram.error as tg_error` in your code and change your except statement to `except tg_error.NetworkError as e:`).

My answer comes a bit late so I hope you found a solution or a workaround before, otherwise I hope this will be usefull to others.