# manage errors in python

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, error-handling

I need to manage python errors. For example when I type:

```
>>> 1/0
```

I give back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

but I need to save this error in a variable.
I use try..except for this:

```
>>> try:
    f(0)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

and see in output:

```
division by zero
```

It's not enough for me. I need to error lines numbers like to IDLE (or other IDE)
(I use python 3.3 and can't use python 2.7)

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508849/how-to-log-python-exception

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to extract specific information such as line numbers:

```
>>> try:
...     f(0)
... except Exception as err:
...     import traceback
...     traceback.print_last()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: tank you, its useful for me.

Comment: its so intrest for me, i can block an error for next time! tank you

Answer (score 1):

You *have* saved the exception in a variable, `err`. It's still bound to the exception, even after the `except` block.

(The fact that `print` on an exception doesn't show all that much is a separate issue.)

However, it sounds like you wanted the traceback object, not just the exception object. That doesn't get automatically bound to a variable for you, but you can do it manually:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

See [`exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) for more information.

But a `traceback` object is a pretty heavy thing, and keeps all kinds of other heavy things alive as long as you store it. One way to avoid carrying around an object as heavy and inter-linked as the traceback is to extract just the information you want from it. That's what the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/traceback.html) module is for:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    exc_traceback = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)
```

Now we're only carrying around a list of small tuples of strings and numbers, instead of the traceback object.

Or, even more simply, just format it immediately:

```
    exc_traceback = traceback.format_tb(exc_traceback)
```

Comment: Tank you.... Your answer is my GOAL..

Comment: i give you 20 point's ;).