# How to get particular exception type that was raised by SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy

Trying to handle an exception raised by SQLAlchemy in my Python code I wrote the following:

```
import sqlalchemy.exc as sqlalchemy_exc

try:
    ...
    db.session.commit()
except sqlalchemy_exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    raise
```

that isn't a good idea as handled exception is too wide. How to get the particular exception type was raised?

**UPDATE**

@Dan presented in his answer a reference where several solutions can be found. Two of them are following:

```
import sqlalchemy.exc as sqlalchemy_exc
    ...
    try:
        ...
    except:
        import sys
        print(sys.exc_info())
```

and

```
import sqlalchemy.exc as sqlalchemy_exc
    ...
    try:
        ...
    except:
        import logging
        logging.exception('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to print it first to see which exception it is: [How to log python exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508849/how-to-log-python-exception)

Then you can modify your code to catch the more specific ones you're interested in handling differently, eventually leaving the printing stuff in the catch-all case at the end - allowing you to identify other specific exceptions you might want to add to your code down the road.

```
try:
    ...
except sqlalchemy_exc.ArgumentError:  # specific exception
    pass  # do something else here if you want
except sqlalchemy_exc.SQLAlchemyError:  # catch-all
    # keep the printing stuff if you want
    raise
```